# How do i assign my Class variable from a String/build Object from String

Tags: java, android

I have a Class that needs to be return a Object built from a String and im not sure whats best to use for my situation.

my string comes in as JSONString and i am splittig it to get key value pairs that look like this.
`variable = "x"`
`value = 60%`

```
public class Math {
    public String x = "";
    public String y = "";
```

Solution 1: this is working but im not able to cast it into class.

```
String variable = keyVal[0];
String value = keyVal[1];
Map m = new HashMap();
m.put(variable, value);
```

Solution 2: I need to reference to Math.x via the `variables` value but thats not working

```
String variable = keyVal[0];
String value = keyVal[1];
Math c = new Math();
c.variable = value;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String variable = keyVal[0];
String value = keyVal[1];
Math c = new Math();
c.variable = value;
```

I think you mean:

```
String variable = keyVal[0];
String value = keyVal[1];
Math c = new Math();
if(variable.equals("x") {
    c.x = value
}
if(variable.equals("y") {
    c.y = value
}
```

You need to do some kind of case distinction, it's not possible to take a String and use it to dynamically determine which field to write to (ok with Reflection it is possible but that would be even more complicated).